# Unable to connect to Kafka server using .net

Tags: c#, .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am unable to connect to Kafka servers from .net. We had truststore.jks file using which we created .pem files using below commands

```
keytool -exportcert -alias $alias -keystore $keyStore -rfc -file $outputFolder/certificate.pem -storepass $password

echo "Generating key.pem"
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore $keyStore -srcalias $alias -destkeystore $outputFolder/cert_and_key.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -storepass $password -srcstorepass $password
openssl pkcs12 -in $outputFolder/cert_and_key.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out $outputFolder/key.pem -passin pass:$password

echo "Generating CARoot.pem"
keytool -exportcert -alias $alias -keystore $keyStore -rfc -file $outputFolder/CARoot.pem -storepass $password
```

and my .net producer config looks like below

```
ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers,
    SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.Ssl,
    SslCaLocation = @"C:\Users\ProduceKafkaMessages\CARoot\CARoot.pem"
};


using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config).Build())
{
    try
    {
        var deliveryStatus = producer.ProduceAsync(topicName, new Message<Null, string> { Value = KafkaMessage }).Result;
        //producer.Flush(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
    }
}
```

But every time it throws exception as "Local: Message Timeout".
Here the config on server is "SSL Enabled Kafka without any ACL enabled".

I have tried same thing in Python and i am able to send kafka topic successfully. Below is the python code

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=kafkaBrokers,
                          security_protocol='SSL',
                          ssl_cafile='CARoot.pem',
                          ssl_password="XXXXX")

producer.send(topic, bytes('hello','utf-8'))
producer.flush()
```

Why it is not working in .net. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
SslCaPem = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\ProduceKafkaMessages\CARoot\CARoot.pem");
```

instead of your

```
SslCaLocation = @"C:\Users\ProduceKafkaMessages\CARoot\CARoot.pem"
```